# TypeError: predict() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 10 were given

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-science, predict

Running a model with 9 inputs and 9 outputs on Keras Functional API.
The model fits just fine, but I'm getting this error when I'm running
 `model.predict`

The model: (note that this is only two input, output- I have 7 more similar layers)

```
one= Input(shape=(9216,))
hidden1 = Dense(dense_one)(one)
hidden1 = BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
hidden1 = Activation('relu')(hidden1)
hidden1= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden1)
hidden1 = Dense(dense_two)(hidden1)
hidden1 = BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
hidden1 = Activation('relu')(hidden1)
hidden1= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden1)
hidden1 = Dense(dense_three)(hidden1)
hidden1 = BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
hidden1 = Activation('relu')(hidden1)
hidden1= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden1)
hidden1 = Dense(dense_four)(hidden1)
hidden1 = BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
hidden1 = Activation('relu')(hidden1)
hidden1= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden1)
output1 = Dense(500, activation='softmax')(hidden1) 

two= Input(shape=(9216,))
hidden2 = Dense(dense_one)(two)
hidden2 = BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
hidden2 = Activation('relu')(hidden2)
hidden2= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden2)
hidden2 = Dense(dense_two)(hidden2)
hidden2 = BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
hidden2 = Activation('relu')(hidden2)
hidden2= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden2)
hidden2 = Dense(dense_three)(hidden2)
hidden2 = BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
hidden2 = Activation('relu')(hidden2)
hidden2= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden2)
hidden2 = Dense(dense_four)(hidden2)
hidden2 = BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
hidden2 = Activation('relu')(hidden2)
hidden2= Dropout(drop_out)(hidden2)
output2 = Dense(500, activation='softmax')(hidden2) 

model = Model(inputs=[one, two...],
              outputs=[output1, output2, output3,output4, output5, output6, output7,output8, output9])
```

This is my fit function:

```
history = model.fit(x=[train1,train2,train3,train4,train5,train6,train7,train8,train9], 
          y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9], callbacks=callbacks,
          batch_size=40, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)
```

It runs perfectly, and I can even plot the history.

Then I'm running:

```
model.predict(train1[1],train1[2],train1[3],train1[4],train1[5],train1[6],train1[7],train1[8],train1[9])
```

And getting the error above.
I checked that the shape of each input is similar to what the model can accept (each train1[x] has the same shape)

Edit:
I tried running

```
model.predict([train1[1],train1[2],train1[3],train1[4],train1[5],train1[6],train1[7],train1[8],train1[9]])
```

And got the following error:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (9216,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I also tried running:

```
model.predict(train1[1:9])
```

And got

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 9 array(s), but instead got the following list of 8 arrays: [array([[255.]... –
```

I also tried running

```
model.predict(train1[1:10])
```

And got

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (9216,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: You are fitting on 9 examples, train1 to train9, but you re trying to predict on train1[0]. Are you sure it is not a bug?

Comment: Not sure how to check if it is a bug

Comment: Can you share a sample of your code? it is not easy to understand what is the real inputs of your model

Comment: Just added a sample code

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, is that you have a model, which is a graph composed of 9 other models. So you have 9 inputs and 9 outputs. each input seems to be of dimension (9216,).

When you fit your model, `train1,train2,...,train9` are the inputs of each of those 9 models. So it makes sense that in the predict, you have the same number of the inputs, I mean train1,train2,..., train9. 
When you try train1[0], it is like you want to get only one element of a tensor of size (9216,) which is not correct

Comment: You understood correctly about the model. I am a bit confused by the explanation though. Let me clarify, each of train1,train2...train9 is a list of arrays of size (9216,) --> similarly to how you would train a model on one array of images (say you have a 100 images, you would put them in an one array called X_train). But when you predict a new image, you don't enter a list of the same size (100) -- you enter one image. Which is why train1[0], train1[1]... are 9 inputs with a size of (9216,) each.

Comment: There are some confusions in linear algebra i guess. Your data comes by the dimension of n. in case of images of size 10*10, in RGB mode, with a flattened image, you will have each image as a vector of size 10*10*3=300. What you give to a model is of the shape of 300 then.  When you define the model, you will only mention the dimension, not the count of the training example. In training, if you have 20 images, your input to the model then will be of the form of 20*300 tensor. And in the test, if you have only one image, you will send a 1*300 tensor to the model to predict.

Comment: Exactly! I was trying to do just that. The only difference that I have 9 sets of images (size of 9216 instead of 300-- you can see that I only gave that dimension). I still don't quite understand how to send "1*300 tensor" or in my case 9*9216 tensor since I have 9 inputs

Comment: But What is the dimension of train1? if it was in a shape like 20*9216, you would not see the mentioned error. Can you make a train1.shape to check it?

Comment: train1 is a list of length 992 (992 images), and each image in in an array of size (9216,)

Comment: It cannot be correct since the error is saying train1[0] is of the shape of (1,). How about to check the train1.shape or train1[0].shape

Comment: I did try to run train1.shape, but since it is a list it has no shape attribute (I can only check its length with len(train1)). I did run train1[0].shape and got (9216,) as I mentioned above